# Caffe without GPU: make runtest error

Tags: caffe

I'm trying to compile caffe without GPU support. I successfully ran "make all" and "make test", but when I try to run "make runtest", I get the following output:

```
   .build_release/tools/caffe
    dyld: Library not loaded: libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3
      Referenced from: /Users/SullyChen/Desktop/caffe/.build_release/tools/caffe
      Reason: image not found
    make: *** [runtest] Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 3):

Copying the lib files from $CAFFE_ROOT/.build_release/lib to /usr/local/lib fixed the problem for me!

Answer (score 1):

This is because caffe library is not linked by default after make all, make test. I manually did the following in terminal:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/YourPathToCaffeMasterFolder/.build_release/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

It fixed the problem for me, for now. Caffe's installation is so much pain.

Comment: I tried this command before I posted the question, unfortunately I still receive the same error